# Facebook API: How to get the inviterID through requestID?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the piece of code I use in javascript to get a the inviterID from a requestID:

```
FB.api(requestID, function (response) {  
   var inviterID = response.from.id;
});
```

Even though I am not a PHP guy, I also found the same approach for PHP:

```
$ret = $facebook->api("/$request_id", 'GET');
$inviterId = $ret['from']['id'];
```

However I am kind of lost how to achieve that in [facebook python SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/).  There is no `facebook.api()` in order to pass in the requestID and get the response object.

Looking at the source code, I couldn't figure out how its done neither.

1. Any suggestions how I can do this please?
2. Is there a good cheat sheet to see the differences between these
   SDK's for future reference?

**UPDATE:**

> I am happy to know any other way to achieve this. Doesn't have to be
>   similar to the solutions in javascript or PHP. Desperate times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use graph.get_object:

   ```
   access_token = facebook.get_app_access_token(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
   graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
   request = graph.get_object("%s_%s" % (request_id, recipient_id))
   inviter_id = request["from"]["id"]
   ```
2. I am not aware of any cheat sheet to see these differences. One option is to check the library code which has some self documentation: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook.py

Comment: Thanks a lot. however your solution requires the access_token, which means the user has to be already to be logged in.  In my case when I invite a friend, I wish to show my picture and name as the inviter to the invitee.  This is due to build trust that the invitee can see his friend has invited him in order to login the app and grant access to his basic profile etc.  I don't think the invitee has any access_token at this stage yet.  You know what I mean?

Comment: I think I got it. You can use the app token instead of the user token,  just keep in mind that the request must include the recipient's ID. I'll change the answer to show this.

Comment: Very interesting solution. However there is no way to get access to the `recipient_id`,  once the unlogged recipient of an invite clicks on the notification --> the URL generated by facebook is like the following: `ImmutableMultiDict([('ref', u'notif'), ('fb_source', u'notification'), ('notif_t', u'app_invite'), ('app_request_type', u'user_to_user'), ('request_ids', u'1403304083217033,374041402724311')])` Darn so close.  Since the current user is not logged in neither has any cookie, I can't get the recipient_id.

Comment: Yes, that's a pitty then! My apps are usually within an App Tab so I do have access to the user ID. How do you get this working with PHP and JS though?

Comment: Derick, I run it as a Canvas (iFrame). You might be right, even in JS you seem to have to be logged in first. In my usecase where the user is invited but hasn't logged in yet, seems to be a limbo state, where I don't know his id yet.  I had a hacky idea, maybe I could send the recipient_id through the request itself as a data. I have to try this...